# Pagination with search function

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

What I'm trying to do is make a search page where the result would be on the same page. My concept is to first show all data and then there will be one textbox and one submit button. Below that, I will show the result which is paginated. How do I achieve that?

```
<input type ="text" placeholder = "search" name = "search">
<input type ="submit" name = "submit">

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
$search = $_POST['search'];
    {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE search = '$search' ";
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            //echo my result here.
        }
    }
```

Comment: Watch out for sql injection `$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE search = '$search' ";`

Comment: I'll take note of that after I've done the functionality

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at jquery and ajax. I did something similar as a test awhile back:

```js
var request = $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: url,
  data: $(".form-wrapper").serialize()
});

request.done(function(data) {
  if (data.search("No results") == -1) {
    $("#result").show();
    $("#result").html(data);
  } else {
    $('#result').html('').hide();
  }
});

request.fail(function(jqXHR, msg) {
  alert(msg);
});
```

```html
<form class="form-wrapper cf">
  <input type="text" id="text" name="q" placeholder="" required>
  <button type="submit" disabled>Search</button>
</form>

<div id="result"></div>
```